# Void tag closure wrapping issue

Tags: jquery, html

this is second part of my first question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352305/jquery-html-method-tags-auto-closure-issue-void-tags?noredirect=1#comment32194709_21352305
If I use :

```
var xml='<parameter name="lg2CacheSize" description="Vex cache size" type="integer" min="12" max="12"/><parameter name="lg2CacheSize" description="Vex cache size" type="integer" min="12" max="12"/>'
$("#dummydiv").html(xml);
```

why does the browser wrap the elements inside each other ?

so instead of parsing like

```
<parameter></parameter>
<parameter></parameter>
```

it parses like

```
<parameter><parameter></parameter></parameter>
```

how can it be parsed as in the first instance ?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/h6dLK/3/ , inspect the black Div to watch the dom tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trying to parse the XML as (invalid) HTML where `<foo />` means "A start tag with a trailing `/`" not "An empty element tag".

It adds the end tags on at the end, because it has got to the end of the string with two open elements still open.

Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOMParser) if you want to parse XML. Don't try to treat it like HTML.

Comment: yes the question is , should it end each seperate tag on its own , not to wrap them inside each other ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek — No. It has no way of knowing where the missing end tags are supposed to be, so it puts them in the first place where they must be.

Comment: so how should i reform my xml so it can be parsed like `<parameter></parameter><parameter></parameter>`

Comment: Ideally - use an XML parser instead of an HTML parser. If you insist on passing it through an HTML parser then use start tags and end tags and don't use empty element tags.